# Visual Studio Code Suggestions Don't Pop Up but Parameter Hints Do

Tags: javascript, dojo, visual-studio-code, code-completion

I'm new to VS Code and am trying to get IntelliSense code completion working for both `dojo` and `arcgis api for javascript`.  I've installed both type definitions globally using typings.  I get parameter hints on methods only after they've been completely typed out but no suggestions while typing.  (I should clarify that I do get suggestions but just not for the methods/parameters I'm looking for.)  I've tried both `jsconfig` and `tsconfig` (with `allowJs` set to `true`) with the same result.

Example for dojo `string substitute()` method:

No suggestions :

[image: No suggestion]

Parameter hints :

[image: Parameter hints]

As you can see from the images , it appears to be referencing the type definitions but for some reason its not providing the suggestions for autocomplete.  I'm obviously missing something or just don't understand how its supposed to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete currently can't be accomplished with JavaScript because of the way dojo asynchronously loads modules.  However, it can be accomplished with TypeScript by tricking ts that your dojo classes are ts classes. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/dojo